# Logstash from multiple processes on the same computer

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash

We are trying to find the best logstash configuration for our application. The application consists of about 30 processes which together make up a server running on a linux machine.

Each of these processes writes to a log file in a dedicated folder. We want to collect these logs and save them to elasticsearch using logstash.

We do have a resource problems though. We won't be able to write to the disk both the logs and keep elasticsearch running with the same data (elasticsearch takes 5x the space of these log files)

For now we thought about trying to pipe the output of each process to it's own logstash which will contain a grok filter and an elasticsearch output, at the same time we will have an elasticsearch instance running on the same machine.

This seems kind of heavy having 30 some instances of logstash running... Is there a better solution? Are we going to get the cpu busted or that's the standard way of doing this kind of thing?

Comment: You can't keep a day's worth of logs on the machine and then delete them after they've been processed by logstash?  How about redirecting stdout to a port, which my google-fu says should be possible.  Also seems hard to believe that you're seeing a 5x penalty for using elasticsearch.

Comment: @AlainCollins A day is too much, we rotate the logs every 10 minutes, keeping up to 10 rotates back. If I let logstash read from these and while it's reading a rotation will happen I'm going to loose logs. Besides, how does logstash handle logrotations?

Comment: The logstash doc says "it handles rotations", FWIW.  If you're worried about those edge cases, configure logstash to only process the most recently rotated file (e.g. logfile.1).  As long as it has a different inode number, you should be ok.

Comment: @AlainCollins This could be O.K, but this still means we are writing the same data to the file system twice (once on files and once on ES) and this also creates other edge cases (For example - a file rotates after 10 minutes if it's larger then a given threshold, what if it never rotates (or just rotates after some very long time)?)... 

We are trying to reduce the output to files mainly because it's slow and we found out it causes a lot of side effects on our system related to performance. Most of our code is legacy code, so changing the critical sections to not write to a file is hard

Comment: Also, sometimes we want to change the debug level to DEBUG, without the system dying on us. Problems begin if some backside process begins I/O intensive operations while the system is running (such as logrotate which may copy over a gigabyte of data every time it runs)

Comment: How about a named pipe?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something, but I think you can have one logstash listening on multiple tcp ports https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-tcp.html

Comment: We considered using sockets, but now it comes to the how. We have a small simple log reporter, we can change it to report to a socket. But this solution does not seem right to me, now we must have logstash running for anyone who links with the log infrastructure. The other solution we had in mind was to pipe the output to a simple c++ program which reads from stdin and writes to a socket. In both solutions we have to deal with the main logstash crashing and other socket related issues. Isn't it simpler to pipe the output into a redis/zeromq/logstash-forwarder client?

Comment: If you pipe stuff, logstash can still crash and you have to be prepared for that.